# Which way to wrap handlebar tape

Tags: handlebar-tape

Seing [this thread](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/how-do-i-wrap-a-road-bike-handlebar) showed me what the tape should be wrapped up from the outside of the handlebars (left side handle wrapped clockwise seen from behind, and vice versa) but looking at some videos at youtube I see that some does it opposite or say that it doesn't even matter. Is this a matter of the bikers way of holding the handles or is there a strict rule I really should stick to when applying my new tape?

Comment: The important thing is to wrap the tape such that the friction of the hand on the handlebar will tighten the tape rather than loosen it.

Comment: (Or just skip the whole issue and use hockey tape -- better overall, IMO.)

Comment: Related question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/is-it-worth-it-to-reverse-the-wrap-direction-of-handlebar-tape-at-the-brake-leve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to your own preferences.

I always wrap mine counter-clockwise on the right side and clockwise on the left side. (seen from riders perspective)..
Edit: You probably shouldn't go the same way around on both sides, thoght. The look and feel would be all wrong ;)

The only tricky part is where you go around the shifters.

Comment: Yes. I always do it the other way. Padded tape forms ridges, and I want them to match my fingers on the top of the bar and on the drops. The important parts are to leave enough at the start to be neatly caught by the bar plugs, and as you say, neatly go round the shifters.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it worked out beautiful

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to wrap them so the friction against your hands when riding tightens rather than loosens it. I find I have to swap the direction of wrapping as I go past the shifters. Start at the bar ends and go "up the inside and down the outside" (cw on right, ccw on left). If you do an extra loop around the shifters you can change direction for the tops.